# Selecting Random Images and displaying them according to Specific Class

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in OOP and working on an assignment in which I have a data of about about 30 images stored in a folder and being read from it in my application. The images consist of **Vegetables**, **Fruits**, **Drinks**, and **Papers**.

I am reading it in class as following:

```
class Objects
{        
    private List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

    Image newspaper = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\1.jpg");
    Image tomatoes = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\2.jpg");
    //  More file paths like these .....

    public Image ReturnImages()
    {
        images.Add(newspaper);
        images.Add(tomatoes); 
        // All images added to the list like this ...

        Random random = new Random();           
        return images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)]; //returns a random image
    }
}
```

How can I identify that the returned image is a Vegetable, Fruit, Newspaper, or a Drink as a random image will be returned from the List? The identification of the returned Image will then help me calling the methods of the specific class i.e Vegetable, Fruit, Papers, and Drink according to the image type returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just giving different names to the variables doesn't help in identifying the image's kind once you store the image reference in a list. You need a specialized class with two properties. kind (an enum with the various image kinds) and an imgData of type Image

```
public class ImageInfo
{
    public ImageKind kind {get;set;}
    public Image imgData {get;set;}
}
public enum ImageKind
{
    Vegetables = 0,
    Fruits,
    Drinks,
    Papers,
}
public class Objects
{        
    private List<ImageInfo> images = new List<ImageInfo>();

    ImageInfo newspaper = new ImageInfo {kind = ImageKind.Papers, imgData = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\1.jpg")};
    ImageInfo tomatoes = new ImageInfo{ kind = ImageKind.Vegetables, imgData = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\2.jpg")};
    //  More file paths like these .....

    public ImageInfo ReturnImages()
    {
        images.Add(newspaper);
        images.Add(tomatoes); 
        // All images added to the list like this ...

        Random random = new Random();           
        return images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)]; //returns a random image
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a minor mistype instead of Image it would ImageInfo in the objects class. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tuple to do that first i would make an enum

```
enum ImageType {
    Newspaper,
    Vegetable,
    Etc..
}
```

then you would use a Tuple

```
private List<Tuple<ImageType, Image>> images = new List<Tuple<ImageType, Image>>();
```

Your function should look like this now

```
private static random = new Random()

public Tuple<ImageType, Image> ReturnImages()
{
    images.Add(new Tuple<ImageType, Image>(ImageType.Newspaper, newspaper));
    images.Add(new Tuple<ImageType, Image>(ImageType.Vegetable, tomatoes)); 
    // All images added to the list like this ...

    return images[random.Next(0, images.Count - 1)]; //returns a random image
}
```